# A custom legend unrelated to data in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to create a custom legend in ggplot that is unrelated to data (as if you added it using the Photoshop)?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

# ================ Mapping =================== 
bas = get_stamenmap(c(-6.3, 53.25, -6, 53.40), zoom=7, maptype="terrain-background")
(mp <- ggmap(bas))


locs <-  data.frame( lon_dec = c(-6.04015), 
                     lat_dec = c( 53.3345))

(big_map <- mp +
    geom_point(data=locs, aes(x=lon_dec, y=lat_dec))  +
    annotate(geom = "text", x = -6.04015, y = 53.3395, label = "1,2,3"))
```

the code gives the below plot (except I added the legend manually using Photoshop):

[image]

I want a legend next to the map saying:

1- A 
2- B 
3- C

Comment: @JonSpring Just edited the code, margin could be removed from the code.

Comment: What do you want the legend to look like? One simple option would be to add another text annotation with the label `label = "1- A\n2- B\n3- C"` but maybe you have something else in mind.

Comment: @JonSpring I have nothing special in mind. Just a guide to what each number represents would work. I find using annotation a bit fiddly but maybe I don't know how to properly do it. So I am curious to see your solution.

Comment: @JonSpring I updated the image with a Photoshopped legend. I can't put the legend outside the map using annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a custom legend like this, it is probably easiest to add it as a custom annotation. You will need to switch to `CoordCartesian` with clipping off to do this.

```r
(big_map <- mp +
    geom_point(data=locs, aes(x=lon_dec, y=lat_dec))  +
    annotate(geom = "text", x = -6.04015, y = 53.3395, label = "1,2,3")+
    theme(plot.margin = margin(20, 100, 20, 20)))

big_map$coordinates <- coord_cartesian(clip = "off")

big_map + annotation_custom(
  grid::textGrob(x = 1.1, y = 0.5, label = "1 - A\n2 - B\n3 - C"))
```

[image]

Comment: not sure if I would directly use the annotate_custom hammer for a simple text annotation.... but it's effective for sure... :) and I personally prefer more programmatic labelling such as `paste(1:3, LETTERS[1:3], sep = " - ", collapse = "\n")` (although not shorter here, this will be more efficient in the long term;)

Comment: @tjebo you're right about the programmatic labelling, of course. Although "annotate_custom hammer" made me chuckle, I would argue that it also saves effort in the long run because its position remains constant if the axis limits are adjusted, so it can be reused. Unless I am overlooking an easier method of drawing text in npc co-ordinates?

Comment: You're right, it might be the best solution for this. I personally usually use something like `y_lab = mean(range(y))` . Not sure if this is really easier though.